# How do I get the position of the cursor of TextEditor in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So in my text editor, I'd like to know the position of the cursor geometrically. I'm also planning to append some text after that position.

So how do I do this?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do that. You would need to use a custom UIViewRepresentable UITextField

Answer (score 1):

Okay... So I figured out a way to do this.

First, I created a `struct` to store the cursor positions

```
import foundation

struct CursorPosition {
    start: Int
    end: Int
}
```

Then I initialize it to be static

```
class Global {
    public static var cursorPosition = CursorPosition(start: 0, end: 0)
}
```

Then finally, I created a custom view to match the SwiftUI `TextEditor` and listen for selection change and update the `CursorPosition`

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

fileprivate struct UITextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView

    @Binding var text: String
    var onDone: (() -> Void)?

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UITextViewWrapper>) -> UITextView {
        let textField = UITextView()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator

        textField.isEditable = true
        textField.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        textField.isSelectable = true
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textField.isScrollEnabled = true
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        if nil != onDone {
            textField.returnKeyType = .done
        }

        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UITextViewWrapper>) {
        if uiView.text != self.text {
            uiView.text = self.text
        }
        if uiView.window != nil, !uiView.isFirstResponder {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, onDone: onDone)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        var onDone: (() -> Void)?

        init(text: Binding<String>, onDone: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
            self.text = text
            self.onDone = onDone
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ uiView: UITextView) {
            text.wrappedValue = uiView.text
        }

        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            if let onDone = self.onDone, text == "\n" {
                textView.resignFirstResponder()
                onDone()
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
                Global.cursorPosition.start = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)
                Global.cursorPosition.end = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: range.end)
            }
        }
        
    }

}

struct EditText: View {

    private var placeholder: String
    private var onCommit: (() -> Void)?

    @Binding private var text: String
    private var internalText: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(get: { self.text } ) {
            self.text = $0
            self.showingPlaceholder = $0.isEmpty
        }
    }

    @State private var showingPlaceholder = false

    init (_ placeholder: String = "", text: Binding<String>, onCommit: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.onCommit = onCommit
        self._text = text
        self._showingPlaceholder = State<Bool>(initialValue: self.text.isEmpty)
    }

    var body: some View {
        UITextViewWrapper(text: self.internalText, onDone: onCommit)
            .background(placeholderView, alignment: .topLeading)
    }

    var placeholderView: some View {
        Group {
            if showingPlaceholder {
                Text(placeholder).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.leading, 4)
                    .padding(.top, 8)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
EditText("", text: $text)
    .onChange(of: text){ _ in
        let cursorStart = Global.cursorPosition.start
    }
```

Comment: it was asked specifically for a solution use TextEditor, not wrapping a uikit view to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322934/14727976) describing how to do it without wrappers (but with a cost of adding `SwiftUIIntrospect` to your dependencies). It uses `TextEditor`, but it works on `TextField` too.

**Note**: I copied it, for convenience. I take no credits for it.

---

### Getting the Cursor Position

You have two options here. Firstly, you can use the [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) package. It allows you to access the underlying UIKit elements used to implement some SwiftUI `View`s. This would look like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Introspect


struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items: [String] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit","Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit"]

    @State private var newItemText : String = ""

    @State private var uiTextView: UITextView?

    @State private var cursorPosition: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
                List{
                     ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                         Text("\($0)")
                     }
                     TextEditor(text: $newItemText)
                        .introspectTextView { uiTextView in
                            self.uiTextView = uiTextView
                        }
                        .onChange(of: newItemText) { newValue in
                            if let textView = uiTextView {
                                if let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
                                    let cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)

                                    self.cursorPosition = cursorPosition
                                }

                            }
                        }.id("New Item TextField")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this approach might break in future versions of SwiftUI, as the Introspect package depends on internal APIs and might no longer be able to extract the `UITextView` from a `TextEditor`.