# How to insert a character into a string in TextEditor in swiftUI?

Tags: string, swiftui, insert, cursor

Are there simple ways to insert a character (arrow) not at the end of the string, but where the cursor is currently located? How can I do that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var text = ""

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    
        Button("➡️"){
            text.append("➡️")
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        
    }
    .padding()
}
}
```

Comment: There's no way to get a cursor position in TextEditor. You can use  a wrapper for `UITextField` though. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367100/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-the-cursor-of-texteditor-in-swiftui